# Can I access the same SQL compact db (sdf) from more than one application simultaneously

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have an existing application that uses SQL Compact Mobile 3.5 and SQL Merge replication to sync with a full SQL database using HTTP.

Can I run another application (exe) on the same device that uses the same db (same sdf file) at the same time.  I understand that SQL Compact Mobile is hosted in process, but could it still be possible?

If so how should I handle synchronisation (I assume I can't sync from both apps at the same time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a SQL Compact Database can be used by separate processes simultaneously  - i.e. it supports multiple concurrent local connections( see the last bullt in the ["features list" here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) if you want an official statement of the fact).  The database will handle locking for you.

Now when you're in the middle of a sync, depending on the lock scheme replication uses, it's quite likely that the process not doing the sync is going to get nothing but lock timeouts.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I don't know what I'd do without SDF and your other contributions.  I'm just about to ask another question which you could no doubt help with.